# TT file generated automatically from EF6 Model renders Default parameter specifiers not permitted error

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, entity-framework-6

Visual Studio 2013 with Update 5,  New Web App project (WinForms) pointing to .NET Framework 4.5, Language C# 5.  I have not created any forms, nor any add-ins, nor any Nu-Get packages to the project.  I have not added any additional References.  I created the project and used NuGet to add Entity Framework 6.1.1.

Disclaimer: I am new to Entity Framework.

I created a very simple SQL Server 2008R2 database with three tables. To the project, I added a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model and pointed it to the database.  The model seems to generate correctly, as well as the corresponding 
.Context.tt, .designer.cs, .edmx.Diagram, and .tt files.

However, when I select to open the .Context.tt file, I get 37 compiler errors including the "Default parameter specifiers are not permitted." on the UsingDirectives Function.  All other errors are syntax errors based on the auto-generated presence of the parameters.  I have searched high and low for someone who has this problem and solutions other than ".NET must be in 4.0" language must be in C# 5.0, because the project is configured that way.  What ELSE could be causing this to exist in my project?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

```
public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
{
    return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
        ? string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}using System;{1}" +
            "{2}",
            inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
            includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
            inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
        : "";
}
```

Comment: I can't post an image, but the code above has the error at the = true) in the declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my problem appears to be the use of DevArt T4 Editor.  Upon recommendation of a training video, I installed this to make Text Templates more readable.  I was using version 1.0.9.  My theory is that this extension was using the .NET 3.5 framework library to do its syntax checking and was creating errors in my error list.  However, the .tt was actually working all along.  I disabled the extension, the errors went away, and I'm continuing on my way.  I hope this helps others who may encounter an inexplicable error in their code.